# How to solve iterative method

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

I m trying to find the time complexity of the following equation:

$$ T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + n^2 $$

I understand that you need to find patterns - so i got this:

$$ 2^2 T(n/2^2) + n^2/2 + n^2 $$
$$ 2^3 T(n/2^3) + n^2/2^2 + n^2/2 + n^2 $$

I don't understand what comes after this- Does this involve using summation of AP/GP?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: When you write "n2", do you mean $n^2$?

Comment: Also, this looks like something you would just plug into the Master Theorem ...

Comment: yes (just edited it). I understand how to use it with Master Theorem - but i wanted to understand using iterative substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to spot a pattern, you should probably start with $n=2^k$ (anyway it's better so that $T(n2^{-i})$ makes sense).

$$\begin{align}
T(2^k) &= 2T(2^{k-1})+2^{2k}\\
       &= 4T(2^{k-2})+2^{2k-1}+2^{2k}\\
       &=8T(2^{k-3})+2^{2k-2}+2^{2k-1}+2^{2k}
\end{align}$$

Now you should be able to guess the pattern. It involves the computation of the sum of a geometric series.